# how to decode hbase timestamp value in python?

Tags: python, hbase, happybase

I am new to hbase and currently I am using hbase-1.2.6. I did the connection to hbase using python script by using happybase package. my question is :
can someone please let me know how to decode timestamp value which is automatically inserted whenever we put any records in table?

```
1.what is the exact interpretation of timestamp value in hbase? 
2.can we convert this timestamp value to yy-mm-dd-hh:mm:ss format?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamp value is the number of milliseconds since the epoch (January 1, 1970 UTC).  You can use the python `datetime` module to manipulate it.  Example:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
print (dt.fromtimestamp(1511356398000 / 1000))

Output: 
2017-11-22 07:13:18
```

The result is a `datetime` object in my local time zone. (Central USA)  The `datetime.fromtimestamp` method wants a floating point value that is the time in seconds since the epoch, so divide the time in milliseconds by 1000.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) is the `datetime` module reference.